# Creating a Table with varying depth and interdependent limits

Tags: list-manipulation, number-theory

As an example I want to find all Integers up to a given limit which only have certain prime factors.
I can do it efficiently for the case of 2, 3, and 5 by

```
g = 100;
t1 = Table[{2^x*3^y*5^z}, {z, 0, Log[g]/Log[5]}, {y, 0, Log[g/(5^z)]/Log[3]}, {x, 0, Log[g/(5^z*3^y)]/Log[2]}]
t2 = Sort[Flatten[t1]]
```

But I am looking for a more general solution where I might have a set of k  different factors. I tried `Nest` but didn' t get far. And I *don't* want to use a function like `FactorInteger` and then `Select` the good ones. I am looking for a solution combining depth of `Table` and a (maybe) recursive function of the limits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for [smooth numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smooth_number). The function `pSmoothOuter` is quite fast, but requires memory as the upper bound `m` grows larger. Input `pmax` is the maximum prime allowed.

```
pSmoothOuter[pmax_Integer, m_] :=
   Block[{s},
      s = 2^Range[0, Log[2, m]];
      Do[
         s = Pick[s = Flatten[Outer[Times, s, p^Range[0, Log[p, m]]]], UnitStep[m - s], 1],
         {p, Prime[Reverse[Range[2, PrimePi[pmax]]]]}];
      Sort[s]]
```

For example,

```
pSmoothOuter[5,10^2]
```

> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 12, 15, 16, 18, 20, 24, 25, 27, 30, 32, 
> 36, 40, 45, 48, 50, 54, 60, 64, 72, 75, 80, 81, 90, 96, 100}

```
AbsoluteTiming[{Total[#], Length[#]} &[pSmoothOuter[30, 10^8]]]
```

> {0.015348, {2364148327261, 88415}}

The following version allows an input list of primes `p`, not necessarily contiguous.

```
pSmoothOuter[p_List, m_] :=
   Block[{s},
      s = Min[p]^Range[0, Log[Min[p], m]];
      Do[
         s = Pick[s=Flatten[Outer[Times, s, q^Range[0, Log[q, m]]]], UnitStep[m - s], 1],
         {q, Most@Reverse[Sort[p]]}];
      Sort[s]]
```

For example,

```
pSmoothOuter[{5, 13, 11}, 800]
```

> {1, 5, 11, 13, 25, 55, 65, 121, 125, 143, 169, 275, 325, 605, 625, 715}

Comment: Wow! Runs like crazy!

Answer (score 2):

This should work.  The construction is unwieldy, and it can be stream-lined, but at least this works:

```
makePrimes[numPrimes_, bound_] := Module[
  {powers = (Prime@Range[numPrimes])^Array[x, numPrimes] // Reverse},
  Sort@Flatten@Table[
    Times @@ powers // Evaluate,
    Sequence @@ MapThread[{#1, 0, #2} &,
      {Reverse@Array[x, numPrimes], 
       Log[bound/Prepend[Most@Exp@Accumulate@Log@powers, 1]]/Reverse@Log@Prime@Range[numPrimes]}
    ] // Evaluate
  ]
]
```

Then

```
makePrimes[3, 100]
(* {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 12, 15, 16, 18, 20, 24, 25, 27, 30, 32, 36, 40, 45, 48, 50, 54, 60, 64, 72, 75, 80, 81, 90, 96, 100} *)
```

is the same list as in the OP's example.