# How to get smooth numbers efficiently by using dependent iterators in Table

Tags: list-manipulation, number-theory

I have the following code for getting smooth numbers up to `Prime[4]` :

```
g = 100;

t1 = Table[{2^x*3^y*5^z*7^u}, {u, 0, Log[7, g]}, {z, 0, Log[5, g/(7^u)]}, {y, 0, Log[3,g/(7^u*5^z)]}, {x, 0, Log[2, g/(7^u*5^z*3^y)]}]
t2 = Sort[Flatten[t1]]
```

I am looking for a general solution for k `Prime`numbers (in ascending order) using `Table` which refers to iterators appearing in the loop before. I know I can use `FactorInteger` and `Select` or fast code from ([Creating a Table with varying depth and interdependent limits](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/228814/creating-a-table-with-varying-depth-and-interdependent-limits/228866#228866))  to solve this problem, but how to tackle it using `Table`? Is there a way to do this? I think the answer lies somewhere in [Table with dependent iterator](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7251/table-with-dependent-iterator)  but here are too many tiwsts for my level of understanding.

Comment: This is somehow relevant https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/ConsecutiveSmoothNumbers

Comment: If you look at the sequence [A002473](https://oeis.org/A002473), there are several codes for mathematica.

Comment: Interesting link! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

g = 100;

t1 = Table[{2^x*3^y*5^z*7^u}, {u, 0, Log[7, g]}, {z, 0, Log[5, g/(7^u)]}, {y, 
    0, Log[3, g/(7^u*5^z)]}, {x, 0, Log[2, g/(7^u*5^z*3^y)]}];

t2 = Sort[Flatten[t1]]

(* {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 14, 15, 16, 18, 20, 21, 24, 25, 27, 28, \
30, 32, 35, 36, 40, 42, 45, 48, 49, 50, 54, 56, 60, 63, 64, 70, 72, 75, 80, \
81, 84, 90, 96, 98, 100} *)
```

Generalizing to `n` primes

```
smooth[n_Integer?Positive, g_Integer?Positive] :=
 Module[{a, func, factors, iterators,
   primes = Prime /@ Range[n],
   vars = Array[a, n]},
  func = Times @@ (primes^vars);
  factors = #[[1]]^#[[2]] & /@ Transpose[{primes, vars}];
  iterators = {#[[1]], 0, Log[#[[2]], #[[3]]]} & /@
    Transpose[{
      Reverse@vars,
      Reverse@primes,
      g/FoldList[Times, 1, Most@Reverse@factors]}];
  Table[func, Evaluate[Sequence @@ iterators]] // Flatten // Sort // Quiet]
```

Checking against original calculations

```
smooth[4, g] == t2

(* True *)
```

Comment: Wow! You put all the puzzle parts together. Like a piece of art! Great! The only part I still have to struggle with is Evaluate Sequence. I read the manual but it is still not very clear to me.

Comment: `Table` requires a **sequence** of one or more iterators. `iterators` is a **list** of the iterators. `Sequence @@ iterators` would convert the list into a sequence. However, since `Table` has the attribute `HoldAll`, the conversion would not be done when it needs to be. `Evaluate` forces early evaluation of this conversion so that `Table` sees the required sequence.

Comment: Thank you for clearing things up!